# How to make a photo appear when clicking on another photo? Javascript, DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have an assignment where I need to make a photo appear when I click on another photo. I need to put each image in an array and call on it to appear when I click on the corresponding photo. When I click on another photo, I need to remove the existing photo and replace it with another one. I need to do it with Javascript and the DOM. I'm unsure how exactly I would do this. Here's my code so far:

```
var photoDiv = getElementById("photos");
    document.getElementById("0").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var img = createElement("img");
        photoDiv.appendChild(img);
    })
```

I know it's completely wrong but I don't know what to do to fix it :(

Comment: Without seeing your html, I'll say that `document.getElementById("0")` seems suspcious.  Please add the relevant html to your question.

Comment: Look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) for an example on how to use the `Image` API to create an image element and append it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the image source of your image.

After this line:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = 'pathto/yourimg.png_or_jpg'; // You need this.
```

Also, it's always a good practice to use document.getElementById() (or putting the parent) instead of just getElementById().

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new image you can also replace only the src of the image element, something like this:

```
// get the image
var imgElement = document.getElementById("myImage");

// add the listener
imgElement.addEventListener("click",
  function () {
    // update the src of the image
    imgElement.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg";
});
```

and that's all, you should not create a new element and append it to the DOM element.